# SQL Query that gives smallest DATE per match

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I've been trying to solve this without a post, but i can't find a fitting answer...

I have a SALE-Table and an APPOINTMENT-Table.
In both is a coloumn sale_id.
In APPOINTMENT is the column do_by(date) which can have several entries per sale_id.

What I need is the NEXT appointment PER matching sale_id.
Sth. like this:

```
appointment_id | sale_id | do_by
--------------------------------------
1365           | 160     | 27.05.2014
2546           | 173     | 29.05.2014
5483           | 265     | 01.06.2014
```

So far my Query only gives me the smallest do_by of ALL...

```
SELECT a.appointment_id, a.do_by, s.sale_id

FROM [Askus7].[CRM7].[APPOINTMENT] a, [Askus7].[CRM7].[SALE] s

WHERE (s.sale_id = a.sale_id) AND a.do_by = 
        (
        SELECT MIN(a2.do_by) 
        FROM [Askus7].[CRM7].[APPOINTMENT] a2, [Askus7].[CRM7].[SALE] s2
        WHERE s2.sale_id = a2.sale_id
        AND s.sale_id = a.sale_id
        )
```

Thx for your help!

Comment: Putting `[]` around table and column names is not MySQL syntax. MySQL uses backticks. That looks like SQL-Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that? (untested)

```
SELECT a.appointment_id, ms.do_by, a.sale_id
(
      SELECT a2.sale_id as sale_id, MIN(a2.do_by) as do_by
      FROM [Askus7].[CRM7].[APPOINTMENT] a2 JOIN [Askus7].[CRM7].[SALE] s2
      ON a2.sale_id=s2.sale_id
      GROUP BY a2.sale_id
)ms
JOIN [Askus7].[CRM7].[APPOINTMENT] a
ON a.sale_id = ms.sale_id and a.do_by = ms.do_by;
```

warning: if you don't have do_by column indexed and your APPOINTMENT table is large, the query might be quite slow.